# Estimating probability based on past stats

Tags: statistics

We've a statistics that counts the number of events calculated over the past 20 years by year. The number of events per year can be a few (1,2,3).

The idea is to calculate a distribution function. Once known we would like to estimate how likely the value of the 'new' year was. Once we've this we can give some hints for looking at the data in detail to see if something is wrong.

Building a histogram graph doesn't give any clear pattern as we don't have enough points.

We're a bit lost, how would you approach this in order to have an estimation of the distribution probability of next year's events ?

Even though it might be a very rough estimation this would be better than nothing.

Comment: Do you want to use your data to argue that the number of events in the upcoming year is likely to be small?

Comment: Do you get any better picture if you widen your bins?  As Ant indicates in their answer, your question doesn't provide enough information to give more specific assistance.

Comment: I've updated the question hope it's clearer now

Comment: So you have $20$ data points, you want to estimate the distribution that generated them, and use it to compute a confidence interval (say, 95%) of next year observation?

Comment: more than looking at a confidence interval, the probability of a next value

Comment: it's important to note that the value is a count of the number of events in an time interval (all the same).

Comment: @ic3 If the distribution is continuos, the "probability of next value" is 0, so you need a confidence interval. Also, you probably need some assumption so make this work. So I'll start: Suppose that the underlying event that $X$ is counting happens with probability $p$, so that $X_i = \sum_{k=1}^N Y_{ik}$,($Y_{ik}$ independent) where $N$ is the maximum number of $Y$ that can happen in a single year. So you find that $X_i \sim Bi(N,p)$ and you can use the MLE to find $p$ ($N$ you probably know?) so that you know the distribution of $X_i$. This tells you everything you need. Clearly this (...)

Comment: is a simplification. You could say "there is not limit to how many times the event happen" (so letting $N \to \infty$), in which case $X$ becoms a Poisson distribution for some parameter $\lambda$. Again use MLE to find $\lambda$ and you have everything. Or maybe $Y_{ik}$ do not follow a discrete distribution, or they are not independent, or what not; in this case you won't be able to say anything. Note that technically we can't find the distribution function of an event by observing it (don't matte how many observations) because you miss a fundamental notion: What is your sample space?

Comment: I mean: if you observe a single observation drawn from a normal distribution, and you ask yourself: what is the distribution function such that the probability of the event I just witnessed is the highest? Well is the distribution function that assigns probability $1$ to that observation and $0$ to everything else. So either you assume something (that is, observation drawn from normal, or whatever) and then you fine-tune the parameter of the distribution, or you're doomed, because you can't really find the "best fitting" distribution, there are too many and the results will not be useful

Answer (score 0):

So you have a time series $x_t$ , from $t=1\dots 20$ and each $x_t \in \mathbb N$.

You want to predict $\hat x_{20}(1)$. This is quite a big topic; you start with a time plot to see if there is any immediate trend or seasonalities. Then you can try to fit an ARIMA process to your observations (based on autocorrelation function, partical autocorrelation function and so on). you could also try different models and choose between them with some kind of criterion (AIC, BIC come to mind).

Then you can predict the next value by using standard methods for predicting an ARIMA process.

I'm afraid I can't really give more help, this is a big topic: you can start with [Chatfield's book](https://www.crcpress.com/The-Analysis-of-Time-Series-An-Introduction-Sixth-Edition/Chatfield/9781584883173).

Or if you don't really care what's going on you can always use some R package to do the estimation.. I think ets is relevant, though I don't remember exactly

Comment: thanks, the question is not clear enough. We're looking for a distribution function as well as an expected average. We would like to say, the value was x% likely if this being very low, check if something is wrong.